# wso2 governance email templates

Tags: wso2, email-templates

We have gotten WSO2 governance registry to send e-mails successfully.  Now we want to template the emails that are being sent out.

There is a sample at :  http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/Governance450/Notification+E-mail+Customization+Sample

This allows you to alter the text coming through the event but is there an easier way that writing Java code?  We cannot compile the sample anyway as the Maven compiler keeps looking up the references files and errors with checksum validation failed.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you need to create an handler to alter the template of emails thus need to have some java code in place. You can use [WSO2 Developer Studio](http://dist.wso2.org/products/developer-studio/2.1.0/docs/registry_category.html#RegistryHandler) to make the process easier.